# Trying to upload data to Parse through HTTPLib in Python

Tags: python, http, parse-platform, httplib

I am trying to upload several files to Parse with HTTLib and the following code:

```
        connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    connection.connect()

    connection.request('POST', '/1/files/' + fileName, open(fileName, 'rb').read(), {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": "6CXB7R7Q6Z6vUVbOqAgBNeDe0bavqfc40QH58fJv",
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "hBDXavBbm2V4xXJX6874MfcWjB9lIrx7DFTlWTbm",
        "Content-Type": "image/png"
    })
    result_pic = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
    print result_pic
```

For the first 10 files or so it worked perfectly. Then all of a sudden it broke. First I couldn't read the responses anymore (result_pic) send me an exception "ResponseNotReady". I changed a few things in my code around and now when I try to establish a connection, I always get a de-coding error of the form:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/untitled/Angel_list_request.py", line 67, in <module>
    "Content-Type": "image/png"
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 827, in _send_output
    msg += message_body
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

No idea what is happening. Something with decoding but I didn't encounter this before at all.

Comment: any odd characters in `fileName`?

Comment: Not really. First I thought that the issue but it uses normal characters and I started removing whitespaces.         
strippedName = name.replace(" ", "")
fileName = (strippedName + ".png")

name is decoded from a JSON file in unicode, i.e. it still has the u'string' before any string.

Comment: @SanjayManohar I played around with the fileName again. It's working now!! Something with the unicode conversion was off

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was the unicode conversion of fileName. Even though fileName was a String I had to force cast it with str(fileName). Everything is working now!